# Segmentation Fault with python class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, memory, segmentation-fault

I was trying to solve this problem of hackerrank.com.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/contacts

But I was getting segmentation fault error (test case 3,4,7,8,12,13) if I tried to make a class which has only one empty dict() as data member.

[Here](https://gitlab.com/Yogintegrate/hacker_rank/blob/master/contacts_trie_data_structure_segmentation_fault.py) is my code.

SOLUTION 1

```
class trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}

root = [trie(),0]
fixed_root = root

def add(root, word,level):
    if level < word.__len__():
        if word[level] not in root[0].children.iterkeys():
            root[0].children[word[level]] = [trie(),0]
            root[0].children[word[level]][1] = root[0].children[word[level]][1]+1
            add(root[0].children[word[level]], word, level+1)
        else:
            root[0].children[word[level]][1] = root[0].children[word[level]][1]+1
            add(root[0].children[word[level]],word, level+1)
    else:
        root[0].children['/'] = None

def frequency_prefix(root, word, level):
    while level< word.__len__():
        if word[level] in root[0].children.iterkeys():
            root = root[0].children[word[level]]
            level +=1
        else:
            return 'not_found'
    return root

def stored_count(root):
    return root[1]

def find(root, word, level):
    f_p = frequency_prefix(root, word, level)
    if f_p == 'not_found':
        return 0
    else:
        return stored_count(f_p)

N = int(raw_input().strip())
for testcase in xrange(N):
    fun, word = map(str, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    if fun == 'add':
        add(fixed_root, word, 0)
    if fun == 'find':
        print find(fixed_root, word, 0)
```

I get no error if I try to run this in my IDE.
I successfully solved the challenge. [Here](https://gitlab.com/Yogintegrate/hacker_rank/blob/master/hr_contacts.py) is the accepted solution. I am using no class in this version of solution.

SOLUTION 2

```
root = [{},0]
fixed_root = root

def add(root, word,level):
    if level < word.__len__():
        if word[level] not in root[0].iterkeys():
            root[0][word[level]] = [{},0]
            root[0][word[level]][1] = root[0][word[level]][1]+1
            add(root[0][word[level]], word, level+1)
        else:
            root[0][word[level]][1] = root[0][word[level]][1]+1
            add(root[0][word[level]],word, level+1)
    else:
        root[0]['/'] = None

def frequency_prefix(root, word, level):
    while level< word.__len__():
        if word[level] in root[0].iterkeys():
            root = root[0][word[level]]
            level +=1
        else:
            return 'not_found'
    return root

def stored_count(root):
    return root[1]

def find(root, word, level):
    f_p = frequency_prefix(root, word, level)
    if f_p == 'not_found':
        return 0
    else:
        return stored_count(f_p)

N = int(raw_input().strip())
for testcase in xrange(N):
    fun, word = map(str, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    if fun == 'add':
        add(fixed_root, word, 0)
    if fun == 'find':
        print find(fixed_root, word, 0)
```

Question

1) I do not understand why I was getting the segmentation fault error in SOLUTION 1. I am using the same memory in both the solutions. I am new with python so I guess I am missing something about python memory management.

Comment: Can you include the exact input for your test case, as well as a copy of the output? I tried solution 1 with a test case from HackerRank and it worked for me.

Comment: A segmentation fault? As in the error message actually uses the phrase "segmentation fault"? That shouldn't happen. Almost nothing in Python can cause that, and I don't see any of the few exceptions in your code.

Comment: Input File Link -https://gitlab.com/Yogintegrate/hacker_rank/blob/master/resources/contacts_input_case3.txt  Output File Link - https://gitlab.com/Yogintegrate/hacker_rank/blob/master/resources/contacts_output_case3.txt . Please note - Even the SOLUTION 1 is running fine in the IDE. Hackerrank has special memory and time constraints. But what I don't understand is I am using equal memory, than why SOLUTION 1 shows segmentation fault.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, the hackerrank shows segmentation fault. But in my IDE, everything works fine.